# Why does this retirement calculator calculate ROI on only half of my savings?

Tags: retirement, calculation, early-retirement

I plugged some example numbers into [the early retirement calculator at Networthify](https://networthify.com/calculator/earlyretirement?income=50000&initialBalance=100000&expenses=15000&annualPct=5&withdrawalRate=4): a $50,000 annual income, $15,000 of annual expenses, and a starting net worth of $100,000.

[image: Screenshot of Networthify’s early retirement calculator]

I’m confused about one of the columns in the table at the bottom: “5% return on investment.” This column seems to be calculated as

ROI = 5% × (previous year’s net worth + ½(income − expenses))

Why is this factor of 1/2 being applied to the savings amount? Is it some kind of averaging to account for the fact that the savings aren’t all present on the first day of the year?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question in your final sentence.  People don't generally invest all of their excess income for the year before they have earned it.

Comment: That’s certainly true. I was thinking that the nature of this calendar (showing you several years at once) might make that irrelevant. Could you turn your comment into an answer?